# normally open or normally closed OptoMos

Tags: opto-isolator, phototransistor

In the following OptoMos [datasheet](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/AQY412S/255-2697-ND/2125662) the OptoMos is defined as Normally closed, when there is no input the output is closed.
But in other OptoMos like the [SFH618A-2](http://datasheet.octopart.com/SFH618A-2-Vishay-datasheet-8477280.pdf) i can't find if the OptoMos is NO or NC.

Comment: OptoMos is totaly different device compared with optocoupler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SFH 618A is turned on by LED current - the symbol of the device is a phototransistor and this can only be turned on by light. A good clue is that this device talks about CTR i.e. current transfer ratio i.e. more LED current means more collector current through the phototransistor.

The OptoMos device appears to be a solid state relay but designed so that light turns the device off.

Comment: So the SFH 618A optocoupler is normally open ?

Comment: Yes it is normally open.